# The Facebook instant game stops after the startAsync function terminates...so how can we call the shareAsync function on button click?

Tags: facebook-instant-games

The instant game only starts when the startasync function is called...and all the fbinstant function only works within the  startAsync function...So how to call shareAsync when user clicks a button

Answer (score 0):

Within the initialization of the page, the init call or event after the start call are great times to add an event listener.

As long as the FBInstant method is called after `startGameAsync` resolves, the share method will work.

Please note that the Instant Games SDK a only works within the Instant Games container. You cannot use the SDK on a different website. If you’re trying to do that, use the regular Facebook JavaScript SDK.

Comment: But the startGameAsync does not waits for an event to happen